# Hide `"ok glass"` menu when enable contextual voice commands

Tags: google-glass

Do you know if it is possible to hide `"ok glass"` bottom text when enable contextual voice commands?

Thanks all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same question is answered here : [how to hide ok glass label from google glass voice menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24808603/how-to-hide-ok-glass-label-from-google-glass-voice-menu)

For now in the XE 19.1, Contextual Voice Commands is not customizable, not even the overlay gray background.

Comment: Thanks! We wait for XE new releases :)

Answer (score 0):

getWindow().invalidatePanelMenu(WindowUtils.FEATURE_VOICE_COMMANDS);

Comment: i tried this but it's not working for me. When do you use it?