# how to hide ok glass label from google glass voice menu

Tags: google-glass

Hi I am developing a application fro Google glass ,I want to hide the "OK glass" command which is essential to launch the menu on voice command so is there a way in which i can launch a menu options on voice command without saying the " OK glass " keyword every time.

kindly guide me on this.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this at the moment using Contextual voice commands. In my opinion, it was for the best, otherwise the Glass user could occasionally select a menu item unintentionally.

Maybe you can implement an alternative using SpeechRecognizer, maybe you'll find [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21652321/how-to-navigate-a-google-glass-gdk-immersion-application-using-voice-command-onl) a bit helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example on how to use a decompiled version of the GlassVoice.apk found on Glass:

https://github.com/pscholl/glass_snippets/tree/master/voiceMenu

which allows to display a menu (or not), display "ok glass" (or not) and add hotwords dynamically (or not). Offline without using the SpeechRecognizer API.